# How to display data in this format from multiple associative array php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to find out in a simple way to display a clean like this format

[image]

Having a hard time to spread the data in this associative array got this from an API

```
Array ( 
    [wind] => Array ( 
        [speed] => 5 
        [direction] => North West 
        [directionDegrees] => 310 
        [unit] => KT 
    ) 
    [visibility] => Array ( 
        [mainVisibility] => 10SM 
    ) 
    [clouds] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [height] => 25000 
            [quantity] => few 
        ) 
    ) 
    [cavok] => 
    [remark] => automated station with a precipitation discriminator sea level pressure of 1021.7 HPa hourly temperature of 17.2°C and dew point of -1.1°C 
    [day] => 6 
    [time] => 22:52:00 
    [airport] => Array ( 
        [name] => Hartsfield Jackson Atlanta International Airport 
        [city] => Atlanta 
        [country] => Array ( 
            [name] => United States 
        ) 
        [iata] => ATL 
        [icao] => KATL 
        [latitude] => 33.6367 
        [longitude] => -84.428101 
        [altitude] => 1026 
        [timezone] => -5 
        [dst] => A 
    ) 
    [message] => KATL 062252Z 31005KT 10SM FEW250 17/M01 A3017 RMK AO2 SLP217 T01721011 
    [station] => KATL 
    [temperature] => 17 
    [dewPoint] => -1 
    [altimeter] => 1021 
    [nosig] => 
    [auto] => 
    [amendment] => 
    [nil] => 
    [corrected] => 
    [cancelled] => 
)
```

I'm not good at programming as this is our assignment from our school I'm looking at to loop the array but I can't seem to find a way how to do it.

Comment: Show us your attempt at least then, please.

Comment: _"like this format"_ - we don't even know what "format" that actually is. It is HTML? Is it plain text? Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry yes in an HTML like the photo I attached. The solution was provided below but the problem is it's missing some data I wanted to have so I have to get the data directly from the API. The problem now is that I can't decode the data as I got this error string(12) "Syntax error" in json_last_error_msg(). I think it's the degree sign it's the problem, can you help how to escape this character?

Comment: If your input data is encoded in UTF-8, then the degree character should not be a problem. If it is not, then you will need to convert to UTF-8 first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this parser source code and make your own solution on the base
https://github.com/SafranCassiopee/php-metar-decoder

or simple way to get field

```
$arr = '$yourDataArrayHere$';
$metarRw = $arr['message']
echo 'Metar message '.$metarRw;
```

```
$airportName = $arr['airport']['name']
echo 'Airport name '.$airportName;
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you I think using a parser is nice but it's missing some data I wanted. So I'm trying the former again I found out that I haven't decoded the data and the problem now is that I got a string(12) "Syntax error" in json_last_error_msg() I think the problem is that the degree sign and I don't know how to escape the character. Can you help?

Comment: @hotdog share the script or repo URL. it's hard to understand your problem without seeing which data get in as input and how the processing